How to use MiKTeX without admin access?
So, a collegue of mine has TeXstudio with MiKTeX on her work computer, which is running Windows 10. She didn't have to tex anything in a while, but recently needed to do so again. Obviously, when trying to use TeXstudio, it complained that MiKTeX didn't have some library updates installed, and she just needed to confirm as admin to install those.
The problem is, on that computer, the admin account is password-locked, but the person with the password has recently passed away.
I installed MiKTeX for her as a user, but now it always complains about admin updates and user updates not being synchronized, and I haven't found any way to fix that that doesn't require access to the admin account, save for resetting the entire OS.
So, my question is, is there any way to separate the user installation and admin installation of MiKTeX, or otherwise use only the user installation without it caring about admin updates?

There is probably a way to what is being asked, but an alternate method is to create a file, place the needed "library" item (.sty, and companion files) is it as well as the document being worked on.

Un-install (if possible) and re-install on AppData.  (Last time I installed it would only install in user mode.)

Somewhat related: if the only admin for the computer has passed away, you will need to reset the entire OS sooner or later.

You can do a TeX Live installation and use this one. But I agree with Teepeemm, that this is more a general Windows administration problem than only a TeX installation problem. So I would recommend to backup all user data and do a fresh Windows installation as soon as possible or ask a Windows expert if there are alternatives to get back a functional admin account.

miktex is available as scoop package (https://scoop.sh). Packages installed with scoop are installed at the user level. Also, installation of scoop itself only requires user permissions.
The docs are sufficient to get going, see https://scoop.sh/#/apps?q=miktex
Regards

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
